# How i get price of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I get price and name of checked item?

```js
var total = 0;
function test(item) {
  if (item.checked) {

    total += parseInt(item.value);

  } else {
    total -= parseInt(item.value);
  }
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + " ";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="5" onClick="test(this);"><label>- Flag A</label>
<- <span class="badge">Price: 5 credits</span><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="13" onClick="test(this);"><label>- Flag B</label>
  <- <span class="badge">Price: 13 credits</span><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="9" onClick="test(this);"><label>- Flag C</label>
    <- <span class="badge">Price: 9 credits</span><br />
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tototal price: <span class="badge"><span id="Totalcost">0</span></span> credits</button>
```

Because this just get of `value="..."` I want show name and price with `id` or `class`

Comment: Maybe a custom `data-` attribute might be of some use to you? For example `data-name="Flag A"`. You could then target that dataset as a way of retrieving the name? If the names are not duplicates then you could always use the `id` attribute to store the name.

Comment: Can you add an example of what the result would look like, with 2 or more checked?

Comment: this is problem i no understand javascript language ... i find this code for example and try edit to show name price,and calculate ...

Comment: Sure I can but first can you be more clear about *"I want show name and price"* Do you mean display the checked items as a list with prices and then a sub total at the bottom?

Comment: Example: 

Please select your admin flags: 
[ ] Flag a - price 5 kredits
[ ] Flag b - price 10 kredits
[ ] Flag c - price 20 kredits

You have selected 0 flags 


----------------When i click Flag a -----
[ x ] Flag a - price 5 kredits
[  ] Flag b - price 10 kredits 
[  ]Flag c - price 15 kredits 

You have selected : a 
and price for  flag a -> this need for my credits system

Comment: Here is a quick demo I have written to show what I were explaining above [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/whumopvs/) if that is what you were looking for I'm sure you can change it up to fit your needs. I wouldn't want to take away all the fun of learning :)

Comment: great thank you so much :)))

Comment: Very welcome. I have changed this one to show the total credits in the button. [**JsFiddle Demo Two**](https://jsfiddle.net/ggjm3kcw/) The rest I will leave to you if this is what you are looking for but if you have problems adapting my demo to your own source code then let me know and I will explain more or provide a answer with more detail and comments within the source code.

Comment: all ready so how i get this subtotal with php ? 
how i explain you know after check you get subtotal any i want this subtotal to check user have kredits or not sorry for bad language again .. still learning :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

@Beytulla, this works for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function buttonClick(){
   var total = 0;
   var type = "";
   for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
     var id = "check_list" + i;
     var label = "label" + i;
     var badge = "badge" + i;
     if (document.getElementById(id).checked!=null && document.getElementById(id).checked==true) {
        total += parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
        type += document.getElementById("label"+i).innerHTML + " : " + document.getElementById("badge"+i).innerHTML + ",";
      }
   }
  document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('individual').innerHTML = type;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list1" id="check_list1" value="5" onClick="buttonClick(this);"><label id="label1"> Flag A</label>  <span class="badge" id="badge1">Price: 5 credits</span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list2" id="check_list2" value="13" onClick="buttonClick(this);"><label id="label2"> Flag B</label>  <span class="badge" id="badge2">Price: 13 credits</span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list3" id="check_list3" value="9" onClick="buttonClick(this);"><label id="label3"> Flag C</label>  <span class="badge" id="badge3">Price: 9 credits</span><br />

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buttonClick()">Total price: 
    <span class="badge"><span id="Totalcost">0</span></span> credits (<span id="individual">0</span>)</button>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This offers exactly the same as the OPs source code.. this doesn't get the name of item or display each item with price.

Comment: right, how this can be the solution to your question? I might missed one step :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
you need to mark your label with an "id" and your input with an attribute "data-index". This is not a complete solution since you still need to deal with the uncheck action, although you can start from this example if you learn doing.

```js
var total = 0;
   
function test(item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    var label = document.querySelector('#label'+ item.dataset.index);
    total += label.innerText + " - " + parseInt(item.value) + " credits; ";  
  }
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = "Labels selected: " + total;
}
```

```html
<input data-index="1" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="5" onClick="test(this);">
<label id="label1">- Flag A</label>
<- <span class="badge">Price: 5 credits</span><br />
  <input  data-index="2" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="13" onClick="test(this);">
<label  id="label2">- Flag B</label>
  <- <span class="badge">Price: 13 credits</span><br />
    <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" name="check_list[]" value="9" onClick="test(this);">
<label  id="label3">- Flag C</label>
    <- <span class="badge">Price: 9 credits</span><br />
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tototal price: <span class="badge"><span id="Totalcost">0</span></span> credits</button>
```

Comment: One small issue you might want to work on or add. The items don't remove from the button when you uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Actually I do not think we should provide the all piece of software but reply to his question with an example, other we became a free software service :D

Comment: If you don't want to provide a solid solution then I would suggest you offer small code snippets within the comments section. The answers/solutions form is for providing solid answers. I know the OP hasn't asked how to remove the items information if unchecked but you should know once running your snippet that will be asked.

Comment: @NewToJS good point, I commented as not complete solution in case he wants to take as starting  example

Comment: It would also appear you have some random things in your `html` between the `label` and `span` elements **<- **

Answer (score 0):

how i get subtotal with php need to check user have subtotal credits if his have send mysql to database and delete subtotal = credits
so i try this

```js
<script>function basket(item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    subtotal = subtotal + parseInt(item.value);
    var basketItem = document.createElement('div');
    basketItem.id = "Basket_" + item.id;
    basketItem.innerHTML = "<span class='badge'>Toplam tıklama sayısı: <span class='badge' style='background-color:red;'>" + item.id + "</span> == " + item.value + " credits</span> ";
    document.getElementById('Yetkiler').appendChild(basketItem);
  } else {
    subtotal = subtotal - parseInt(item.value);
    document.getElementById('Basket_' + item.id).remove();
  }
  document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Total: <span class='badge'>" + subtotal + " credits</span>";
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php 

$price1 = "10";
$price2 = "20";
$price3 = "30";

how i do this 
 if($user['kredits'] > here subtotal){
?>
<form method="post">
<input id="150" type="checkbox" name="max_clicks" onClick="basket(this);" value="<?php echo "".$price1."";?>" />
<label for="150">150 Tık</label><- <span class="badge">Fiyat: <?php echo "".$price1."";?> kredi</span>
<br/>
<input id="400" type="checkbox" name="max_clicks" onClick="basket(this);" value="<?php echo "".$price2."";?>" />
<label for="400">400 Tık</label><- <span class="badge">Fiyat: <?php echo "".$price2."";?> credits</span>
<br/>
<input id="735" type="checkbox" name="max_clicks" onClick="basket(this);" value="<?php echo "".$price3."";?>" />
<label for="735">735 Tık</label><- <span class="badge">Fiyat: <?php echo "".$price3."";?> credits</span>
<br/>

<div id="Yetkiler"></div>
<span id="subtotal"></span> 

<input  class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" type="submit" name="add_ad" value="Reklam satın al"
</form>
<?php } ?>
```